Member pointer template parameter pointing into the object being templated
I would like to have a base class that I derive from that offers serialization mechanism:
template <typename Type, typename Class, Type Class::* Member>
class Serializable
{
    public:
    void Serialize();
};

template <typename Type, typename Class, Type Class::* Member>
void Serializable<Type, Class, Member>::Serialize()
{
    // accessing the member variable we're pointing to, to do stuff with it
}

The idea is that if I derive Foo from Serializable, I could template it so that Foo::x is used as the template parameter. This way, when I call the base Serialize, it knows to serialize the x member of Foo. So I'd be able to do something like:
class Foo : public Serializable<int, Foo, &Foo::x> // <<-- issue here
{
public:
    int x, y;
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;

    foo.x = 32;
    foo.y = 10;

    foo.Serialize();

    return 0;
}

I don't see how to template Foo so that Serializable gets to know that Foo::x is the member to serialize. It seems to work well to have Type and Class properly templated, but it complains Foo is incomplete at this point. It feels so close...
The end goal is that Foo stays as simple as it is in memory, but the templated Serialize() function knows x is the member to read. If I get it to work, then I can use further metaprogramming to have multiple members serialized.
How would I achieve that? (getting the correct pointer to member)

Pass Foo::x to a protected Serialize(x) template. Override Serializable::Serialize() with Foo::Serialize() that calls Serialize(x). See https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/ as an example.

I hope this to all work without a virtual function. Every time people bring up metapgrogramming they rave about how it's all compile time, zero cost. Why would I pay at runtime here, for something the compiler can do at compile time? (storing which members need serialization in which order)

Don't communicate w/ such people. Compilers are able to optimize virtual calls since a while.

Currently you can do automatic serialization for aggregate types. When p1061 makes it in the Standard, you will be able serialize decomposable types with variadic structured bindings auto&& [...members] = foo, you can experiment with clang_p1061 branch.

At the point where &Foo::x is being passed to the base class, Foo::x hasn't been declared yet. That is why the compiler is complaining about Foo being incomplete. Nothing you do will allow you to pass around an unknown member.  You need to rethink your design.

@RemyLebeau sure, but my hobby is finding questions whose obvious and correct answer is "C++ won't let you do that" amd doing it anyhow ;)

When you use template class as base class the compiler will geberate different one for each child has different args so it will add extra effort if you to make collections of these classes instancses; for me i prefer using virtual functions instead

#define RETURNS(...) \
  -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__) \
  noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) \
  { return __VA_ARGS__; }

#define MEMBER(...) \
  [](auto* self) \
  RETURNS( self->__VA_ARGS__ )

Now, MEMBER(x)(foo) acts like a member pointer.  If you really need a member pointer,
#define MEMPTR(...) \
  [](auto* self) \
  RETURNS( &std::decay_t<decltype(*self)>::__VA_ARGS__ )

Now, MEMPTR(x)(foo) is &Foo::x.
The trick is both of these do not require the class to be defined prior to using them, as they get their class type later.  They just need the member name.
You simply change:
template <class Derived, auto Member>
class Serializable

then either use Member(static_cast<Derived*>(this)) and either extract Type Class::*Member or just get a direct reference to this->Member.
The child looks like:
class Foo : public Serializable<Foo, MEMPTR(x)>

and can be easily extended to
class Foo : public Serializable<Foo, MEMPTR(x), MEMPTR(y)>

(or the MEMBER versiom).
The MEMPTR one gets you the exact type (if needed), while MEMBER just gets you access to it (an int& cannot be distinguished as easily from an int&&).

You are explicitly listing the class members to serialize anyway, why not just write Serialize(x,y) function in the class. It has obvious advantages of not dealing with cryptic macros, not as easy to overlook changes in the class when modified, and doesn't depend on member accessibility.

@Gene I mean, I don't write specifications, I just solve the OP's problem.  :)
